# Not able to consume item - cannot resolve consumeAsync

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I am following google sample to setup in app billing in my app. I have succesfully integrated in app billing api. But when i call `consumeAsync();` Android studio says cannot resolve method consumeAsync
[image]

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh no, there was a problem.
                    Log.d("BillingAPI", "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
                } else {

                    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener
                            mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
                        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
                            if (result.isFailure()) {
                                // handle error
                                return;
                            } else {                                
                                boolean isPurchased = inventory.hasPurchase(REMOVE_ADS);
                                Log.d("Is this app owned?", isPurchased + "");

                                IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
                                        if (result.isSuccess()) {
                                            // Purchase consumed.
                                        } else {
                                            // Purchase not consumed.
                                        }
                                    }
                                };

                                if (isPurchased) {
                                    mHelper.consumeAsync(isPurchased, mConsumeFinishedListener);
                                }
                            }                            
                        }
                    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out it was pretty stupid mistake.

`consumeAsync` expect its first parameter to be `Purchase` i was passing a `boolean`

Instead of doing this

```
boolean isPurchased = inventory.hasPurchase(REMOVE_ADS);
mHelper.consumeAsync(isPurchased, mConsumeFinishedListener);
```

I needed to use `getPurchase` instead of `hasPurchase`

```
Purchase purchaseInfo = inventory.getPurchase(REMOVE_ADS);
mHelper.consumeAsync(purchaseInfo, mConsumeFinishedListener);
```